# What is the best file system to use for a second hard drive when dual booting between WinXP and Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

I am dual booting for legacy reasons, and I have a 2nd internal drive that I would like to use from both XP and 7.

Should I go with the standard NTFS? (will the secuirty features be an issue, with different SIDs from the different users)

Should I go with FAT32?

Should I try out the new exFAT?

Also, I curently have two of my 3 drives as "dynamic disks" and 1 spaned volume created on them. (i did this from XP)  Win7 can see them/it fine. Is this an ok thing to do?

Comment: As this question concerns the operation of a single computer, it is better suited for Superuser.com.  Please do not re-post, as it will likely be relocated on your behalf.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/130120/what-is-the-best-file-system-to-use-for-a-second-hard-drive-when-dual-booting-bet, perhaps we can migrate and close this one?

Comment: No, this is a superuser question.

Comment: However, the information in that link is still asking the same question and i would still put the same answer for the first part. Personally I'd always go NTFS unless someone can explain why that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As both Windows XP and Windows 7 can handle NTFS natively, that's obviously the best choice. Nobody should use FAT32 anymore if not forced to, because of its notorious unreliability and poor performance.

In order to avoid SID issues, you can either don't restrict permissions (if you don't need that much security) or assign them to default groups (administrators, users) whose SIDs is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

Personally i would go with NTFS. It's supported by both of them (and it's what's suggested in the duplicate of this question on serverfault).

As for the dynamic disks there won't be any problems that I know of unless you want to split them up later or you try to use windows 7 to edit them. at vista they introduced a new system that xp doesn't work well with, so if you're going to keep your dynamic disk then you're going to have to make sure to do the editing of that system in windows xp instead of windows 7.

The wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) offers more than i know about it so feel free to give that a look through

hope that helps.

Comment: +1: can't go wrong with NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use exFAT, you need a KB patch for XP/2003. eFAT does not support file permissions, and you can't install the W7 OS on exFAT. NTFS would be best.